# Adding encoding alias to python

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

Is there a way that I can add alias to python for encoding. There are sites on the web that are using the encoding 'windows-1251' but have their charset set to win-1251, so I would like to have win-1251 be an alias to windows-1251

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `encodings` module is not well documented so I'd instead use `codecs`, which [is](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html):

```
import codecs

def encalias(oldname, newname):
  old = codecs.lookup(oldname)
  new = codecs.CodecInfo(old.encode, old.decode, 
                         streamreader=old.streamreader,
                         streamwriter=old.streamwriter,
                         incrementalencoder=old.incrementalencoder,
                         incrementaldecoder=old.incrementaldecoder,
                         name=newname)
  def searcher(aname):
    if aname == newname:
      return new
    else:
      return None
  codecs.register(searcher)
```

This is Python 2.6 -- the interface is different in earlier versions.

If you don't mind relying on a specific version's undocumented internals, @Lennart's aliasing approach is OK, too, of course - and indeed simpler than this;-). But I suspect (as he appears to) that this one is more maintainable.

Comment: Great point Alex! --- Do no use a module which does not have a great documentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import encodings
>>> encodings.aliases.aliases['win_1251'] = 'cp1251'
>>> print '\xcc\xce\xd1K\xc2\xc0'.decode('win-1251')
MOCKBA
```

Although I personally would consider this monkey-patching, and use my own conversion table. But I can't give any good arguments for that position. :)

Comment: Alex did provide a good argument for that position above. :-)
I think the official way is too much work, and would still simply provide my own conversion list, but that is not always feasible

Comment: Maybe point out that the `encodings.aliases.aliases` keys are normalized.  This is how `'win-1251'` in the `decode()` argument, with a dash, maps to `'win_1251'` with an underscore internally. The other way around doesn't work; a human-readable encoding name with a dash needs to be represented with an underscore in the alias key.

Answer (score -1):

Encoding aliases can be added by editing aliases.py file.

```
# euc_jp codec
'eucjp'              : 'euc_jp',
'ujis'               : 'euc_jp',
'u_jis'              : 'euc_jp',
'euc_jp_linux'       : 'euc_jp',
'euc-jp-linux'       : 'euc_jp',
```

Above I have added two aliases **euc_jp_linux** and **euc-jp-linux** to the encoding **euc_jp**.

For a 64 bit linux system aliases.py file is generally located under /usr/lib64/python2.6/encodings/