# Decoding email text with bytes.decode(encoding)

Tags: python, email, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to decode some email text with Python 3's `bytes.decode(encoding)`, where `encoding` is sourced from the `charset` field of an email header.

Problem: some emails list 'cp-850' as their charset while `decode()` accepts 'cp850'.

If I simply get rid of the hyphen, then another codeset like iso-8859-6 becomes iso88596, which is an unrecognized encoding.

How do I sanitize the arg `encoding` without creating more unknown encodings?

[Edit] Follow up question: How do I get obtain the charset from an `email.message.Message` object in a format (alias) that is accepted by `bytes.decode()`?

[Edit] Clarified the question. Previously used an incorrect term 'content encoding' when I meant the charset.

Comment: There is a way to add aliases for encodings, but the `email` module should already know how to map IANA encoding names to Python's internal labels. You really should not be doing your own email parsing unless you know for a fact that the `email` library doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @tripleee Hi, do you mean that the `email` module automatically figures out what content encoding each message is after parsing? As in, after parsing an email with (for example) `email.message_from_binary_file()`, the returned `Message` object will automatically figure out the content encoding of the email?

Comment: Yes, it can parse email messages and present to you a reasonably unified structure of MIME parts from which you can extract already-decoded text if it's a text part.

Comment: ("Content encoding" in this context is a different thing. You are looking at the `charset=` value of the content type.)

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry. I mean the charset: I want to get the correct charset of whatever text (plain or html) in the message. Hopefully in a format (or alias) that `bytes.decode()` accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the hyphen and check if there is a codec that supports the resultant encoding:

```
import codecs

def sanitize_encoding(enc):
    try:
        codecs.lookup(enc)
        return enc
    except LookupError:
        try:
            enc = enc.replace('-','')
            codecs.lookup(enc)
            return enc
        except LookupError:
            # Not a thing, either way
            return None

sanitize_encoding('cp-850')
#'cp850'
sanitize_encoding('iso-8859-6')
#'iso-8859-6'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`email.charset` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.charset.html) contains a mapping from IANA character-set labels to the aliases used internally by Python<del>; but chances are you won't need to do this yourself at all</del>.

Here is an adaptation of the example from the [`email` module's Examples page in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

```
import email
from email.policy import default

with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as fp:
    msg = email.message_from_binary_file(fp, policy=default)

for part in msg.walk():
    # multipart/* are just containers
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    charset = part.get_content_charset()
    if charset is not None:
        print('=== charset {} ==='.format(charset))
        print(part.get_content())
```

This will get you the IANA character set label for the part's character set; but (by the default `email.policy`) the text payload will have been decoded into Unicode for you, so you should not need to convert it yourself at all.

The `email` library was officially overhauled in Python 3.5 (the overhaul was unofficially introduced  already in Python 3.3) with a policy-based system which allows you to take over some parts of message parsing if you really need to; but for well-formed standards-conformant messages (and some common mutations seen in the wild), you can just sit back and let the Python standard library do the work for you.

**However,** as you note, the code actually fails to work with `cp-850` body parts, precisely for the reasons you state.  You would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```
# FIXME: broken code, doesn't help
import email.charset as email_charset
email_charset.add_alias('cp-850', 'cp850')
```

Instead, you have to [hack Python's `encodings` module to support this alias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1064191/874188):

```
import encodings
encodings.aliases.aliases['cp_850'] = 'cp850'
```

Notice also how, bewilderingly, the alias has an underscore which then gets mapped to a dash in some internal black voodoo magic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code snippet! I tested it and found that when I attempt to do `part.get_content()`, it still got tripped up by sub-messages encoded in cp-850 :(
The traceback indicated that `contentmanager` could not find the encoding cp-850.
``` File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/contentmanager.py", line 67, in get_text_content
  return content.decode(charset, errors=errors)
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp-850```

Comment: It works for me with `get_payload(decode=True)` instead of `get_content()`. I have updated the answer to show this, too.  Maybe there is a bug in `get_content()`...?

Comment: Turns out `get_text_content()` calls `get_payload(decode=True)` and then tries to `.decode` the result ... I'm not sure this code is correct; the payload should already be decoded. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/email/contentmanager.py#L67

Comment: ... Wait, that's not correct either; it decodes into a byte string. So the code is correct after all and there's something up with the cp-850 codec just like you stated.

Comment: Yes, because `.decode()` expects 'cp850' (no hyphen) instead of 'cp-850'.

Comment: The `email` module probably gets the charset straight from the email header without checking if the codeset name is valid. Anyway, thank you so much for taking the time to help!